# how to avoid a coil turning into a magnet when energy is dragged out of it ? is there any solution at all?

Tags: motor, generator, energy

when a generator is generating electricity and at certain point we try to get the energy out of the coil, thus resulting in the reduction of RPM due to the coil acting as magnet. 
is there any way to avoid the coil turning itself into a magnet and still recover the energy.

Comment: "thus resulting in the reduction of RPM due to the coil acting as magnet" -- Newton's laws imply that for energy generation to be possible, a rotary generator must receive some torque at some positive RPM, according to \$P_{generated} =\tau \times \omega \$, thus "slowing down" the mechanical load with torque \$ \tau \$.

Comment: When you take energy out you convert mechanical energy to electrical energy. There's not really much you can do about that. What you however can do is use a gearbox or a flywheel so the effect won't be as noticeable or easier to deal with.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is asking how to build a perpetual motion machine.

Answer (score 5):

Power_out = power_in minus losses. You can't get something for nothing when it comes to the transfer of energy.

I'm trying to think of something else to add to this but I don't think there is. It's about as simple as it comes.

Comment: This does not deserve a downvote.

Comment: I agree Brian lol

Answer (score 4):

The coil doesn't  generate energy.

All it does, in your "generator", is convert energy from mechanical to electrical. So the answer is, obviously, no.

For example, you could orient the coil differently, say, outside the stator's magnetic field so that it exerted no magnetic force on the driving shaft - but then it would generate no electricity.

Answer (score 3):

This is to add to Brian and Andy's answers a little.

It's precisely because the coil acts as a magnet that it is able to turn the mechanical input energy into electrical output.

Think of the current-carrying coil as a 'lever', spanning the mechanical and electrical domains.

It's obvious that a mechanical-to-mechanical lever provides a both-ways connection between input and output, and that all the energy output comes from the input, less some friction at the pivot.

It only becomes obvious that the same is true for the coils in motors and generators, here the energy is lost resistance and eddy currents as well as friction, after you've met plenty of examples, and gone through the physics a few times.